# Как считать данные из таблицы Exell, используя Python3 и Pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, excel, pandas, xlsx

Дан файл Excel 2007, требуется, используя Python3 считать из него данные и вывести в виде таблицы, с помощью Pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_excel ('C:\\ Users \\ User \\ Desktop\\demo11.xls',u'Лист1', header=4, parse_cols="A:B",skip_footer=2, index_col=0)
c = data.rename(columns={u'Все':'PeopleQty'})
```

А когда пытаюсь вывести `data` падает ошибка `No module named 'xlrd'`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что пробовали делать? Что не получается?

Comment: [Доку](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/cookbook.html#excel) уже прочитали? В чем возникли трудности?

Comment: Я новичок, установил python3 с использованием Anakonda3.

Comment: Файл Excel считывал так:

Answer (score 2):

Для того, чтобы работать с файлами Excel, требуется соответсвующий драйвер. Он находится в пакете `xlrd`. Установите его, сделайте `pip install xlrd`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_excel ('C:\\ Users \\ User \\ Desktop\\demo11.xls',u'Лист1', header=4, parse_cols="A:B",skip_footer=2, index_col=0)
c = data.rename(columns={u'Все':'PeopleQty'})
```

Comment: а когда пытаюсь вывести 'data' падает ошибка 'No module named 'xlrd''

Comment: Я перенес код и пояснение к нему в вопрос, а этот ответ удалите